# Syncing independent applications. (How to check if a file was modified by another program on runtime)

Tags: c++, linux, windows, file, file-sharing

It is easier to explain with example.

When 2 text editors edit the same text file in the same time, when one editor saves the file, the other one understands that it was modified and asks to do smth.

How is it possible to get a signal that a file was modified outside the program?

I am working with c++ (though I think it isn't important) and on linux. (solution for windows would be good too)

Comment: Socket communication can be a solution (it's portable and relatively generic) for pushing notifications. A active listener (polling) is another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO-C++ does not offer this functionality, so you have to stick with what the operating system provides.

On Linux that would be [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), on Windows you would use [directory change notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: A little late but I hope you will answer. Will inotify work "live". Do I need to constantly ask inotify to give information or will it signal me in some way as soon as file/directory was modified?

Comment: @khajvah `inotify_init` returns a file descriptor which is used as the basis for all operations. You can use this just as you would use a socket for network I/O: You can `read()` on it from a worker thread, which will block (i.e. sleep) until a change occurs. Alternatively, use your favorite asynchronous I/O technique to avoid blocking a thread.

Answer (score 1):

① Check the timestamp of the file as close as possible before writing.  If it is not what it was when you last opened this file for reading, then beware!

② You can build a checksum of the file and compare this to one you built earlier.

③ Register to a system service which informs you about file activities.  This depends on the goodwill of the OS you are using; if this notification service isn't working properly, your stuff will fail.  On Linux have a look at Inotify.

Comment: Using one of the first two ways, you could even create a thread in your application that polls for modification regularly, say, once every couple of seconds. Just in case notification by the OS is out for some reason.